# Simple C++ program not compiling using wstrings and cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I´m building this simple C++ program using Visual Studio 2012:

```
#include <stdafx.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << "Hello World...";

    std::string input_data;

    std::string output_data("Hello. Please type your name");

    std::wcout << output_data;
    std::wcin >> input_data;

    std::wcout << "Your name is " << input_data;

    return 0;
}
```

I can´t compile. Getting the followig errors:

```
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::wistream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>> << std::string    

IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::wostream << std::string

IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::wistream >> std::string
```

Can someone help me to fix that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try changing all `std::string` ocurrences for `std::wstring`... or all `wcin`/`wcout` for `cin`/`cout`... (in the first case, prefix the strings like `L"aaa"` This, for instance, works perfectly:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << L"Hello World...";

    std::wstring input_data;

    std::wstring output_data(L"Hello. Please type your name");

    std::wcout << output_data;
    std::wcin >> input_data;

    std::wcout << L"Your name is " << input_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clear and consise... Great! Thanks for help... Working fine in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could switch everything to narrow strings:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World...";

    std::string input_data;

    std::string output_data("Hello. Please type your name");

    std::cout << output_data;
    std::cin >> input_data;

    std::cout << "Your name is " << input_data;

    return 0;
}
```